# Python: How can I calculate the average word length in a sentence using the .split command?

Tags: python, python-3.x

new to python here. I am trying to write a program that calculate the average word length in a sentence and I have to do it using the .split command. btw im using python 3.2

this is what I've wrote so far

```
sentence = input("Please enter a sentence: ")
print(sentence.split())
```

So far i have the user enter a sentence and it successfully splits each individual word
they enter, for example: Hi my name is Bob, it splits it into ['hi', 'my', 'name', 'is', 'bob']

but now I'm lost I dunno how to make it calculate each word and find the average length of the sentence.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In Python 3 (which you appear to be using):

```
>>> sentence = "Hi my name is Bob"
>>> words = sentence.split()
>>> average = sum(len(word) for word in words) / len(words)
>>> average
2.6
```

Comment: Wow it worked, thanks! All these answers are amazing but i just used this one. Btw what does len do exactly?

Comment: Quoting [the docs](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#len): It returns the length (the number of items) of an object. In a string, that's the number of characters, in a list, it's the number of items etc.

Answer (score 8):

You might want to filter out punctuation as well as zero-length words.

```
>>> sentence = input("Please enter a sentence: ")
```

Filter out punctuation that doesn't count. You can add more to the string of punctuation if you want:

```
>>> filtered = ''.join(filter(lambda x: x not in '".,;!-', sentence))
```

Split into words, and remove words that are zero length:

```
>>> words = [word for word in filtered.split() if word]
```

And calculate:

```
>>> avg = sum(map(len, words))/len(words)
>>> print(avg) 
3.923076923076923
```

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> sentence = "Hi my name is Bob"
>>> words = sentence.split()
>>> sum(map(len, words))/len(words)
2.6
```

Answer (score 1):

The concise version:

```
average = lambda lst: sum(lst)/len(lst) #average = sum of numbers in list / count of numbers in list
avg = average([len(word) for word in sentence.split()]) #generate a list of lengths of words, and calculate average
```

The step-by-step version:

```
def average(numbers):
    return sum(numbers)/len(numbers)
sentence = input("Please enter a sentence: ")
words = sentence.split()
lengths = [len(word) for word in words]
print 'Average length:', average(lengths)
```

Output:

```
>>> 
Please enter a sentence: Hey, what's up?
Average length: 4
```

Comment: Personally, I think adding a lambda into the mix makes it less clear.

Comment: I agree with Lennart, if the function deserves a name, use `def` rather than `lambda`

Comment: Actually I agree, but I wanted to separate the calculation of the average for him.

Answer (score 0):

```
def main():

    sentence = input('Enter the sentence:  ')
    SumAccum = 0
    for ch in sentence.split():
        character = len(ch)
        SumAccum = SumAccum + character

    average = (SumAccum) / (len(sentence.split()))
    print(average)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  def averageWordLength(mystring):
tempcount = 0
count = 1

wordcount = 0
try:
    for character in mystring:
        if character == " ":
            tempcount +=1
            if tempcount ==1:
                count +=1

        else:
            tempcount = 0
            try:
                if character.isalpha(): #sorry for using the .isalpha
                    wordcount += 1
            except:
                wordcount = wordcount + 0
    if mystring[0] == " " or mystring.endswith(" "): #i'm sorry for using the .endswith
            count -=1

    try:
        result = wordcount/count
        if result == 0:
            result = "No words"
            return result
        else:
            return result

    except ZeroDivisionError:
        error = "No words"
        return error

except Exception:
    error = "Not a string"
    return error
```

mystring = "What   big spaces   you  have!"
output is 3.0 and I didn't use the split

Answer (score 0):

as a modular :

```
import re

def avg_word_len(s):
    words = s.split(' ') # presuming words split by ' '. be watchful about '.' and '?' below
    words = [re.sub(r'[^\w\s]','',w) for w in words] # re sub '[^\w\s]' to remove punctuations first
    return sum(len(w) for w in words)/float(len(words)) # then calculate the avg, dont forget to render answer as a float

if __name__ == "__main__":
    s = raw_input("Enter a sentence")
    print avg_word_len(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = input("Please enter a sentence: ")
avg_word_len = len(s.replace(' ',''))/len(s.split())
print('Word average =', avg_word_len)
```

Output:

```
Please enter a sentence: this is a testing string
Word average = 4.0
```

note: this is a plain vanilla use case, additional boundary conditions can be applied as required.

Answer (score 0):

```
text = input()

words=text.split()
single=''.join(words)
average=len(single)/len(words)
print(average)
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score -1):

```
def average():
    value = input("Enter the sentence:")
    sum = 0
    storage = 0
    average = 0

    for i in range (len(value)):
        sum = sum + 1
        storage = sum
        average = average+storage

    print (f"the average is :{average/len(value)}")

    return average/len(value)

average()
```

Comment: I doubt that this helps, or even works at all. To convince me otherwise please explain how this works and why it is supposed to solve the problem described in the question.