# Python - Return Average of Word Length In Sentences

Tags: python, string

I have a question very similar to this one: [Python: How can I calculate the average word length in a sentence using the .split command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12761510/python-how-can-i-calculate-the-average-word-length-in-a-sentence-using-the-spl)

I need the average word length for multiple sentences. Here's what I currently have. I'm getting the average of all the words when I want it by sentence. Also getting a 0 at the end of the first row that's produced.

```
words = "This is great. Just great."
words = words.split('.')
words = [sentence.split() for sentence in words]
words2 = [len(sentence) for sentence in words]
average = sum(len(word) for word in words)/len(words)
print(words2)
print(average)
```

Comment: What about punctuation? If you are getting 0 you are probably using python2 so you need to use `/ float(len(words))` or import truediv

Comment: This is a good example on how good naming helps with analyzing logic. Converting `text` to list of `sentences` to list of list of `words_in_sentences` and computing average from there is slightly easier than converting `words` to `words` to `words` to `words2` to `average`. You now what to expect in each step and can quickly isolate which step fails. It's not that easy right now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
sentences = words.split('.')
sentences = [sentence.split() for sentence in sentences if len(sentence)]
averages = [sum(len(word) for word in sentence)/len(sentence) for sentence in sentences]
```

Comment: Could be wrong, but isn't this counting `.` as part of the word length?

Comment: Not sure how this got upvoted twice.  No improvement over the OP's code, and you have `ZeroDivisionError`.

Comment: @wim fixed.  Forgot that `split` behaves that way when given characters.

Comment: This seems to work on it's own. When I apply it to my actual project, I'm getting a ZeroDivisionError on the averages line. :/

Comment: @ChristopherFlach move `if len(sentence)` to the averages line

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Ha, I noticed that right as I saw your message. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

lets look at this line

```
average = sum(len(word) for word in words)/len(words)
```

here the len(words) = 2 this is not the len of words . it is the len of sentence

```
average = sum(len(word) for word in words)/(len(words[0])+len(words[1]))
```

hope you get the idea

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
data = "This is great. Just great."
sentences = data.split('.')[:-1]    #you need to account for the empty string as a result of the split
num_words = [len(sentence.split(' ')) for sentence in sentences]
average = sum(num for num in num_words)/(len(sentences))
print(num_words)
print(len(sentences))
print(average)
```