# Issue with program that counts the average word length

Tags: python, python-3.7

I am very new to Python so I am only familiar with some very basic functions and I am doing an exercise on loops. I need to build a program that counts average word length. Here is my code:

```
sentence = input ("Give your sentence:")
words = len(sentence.split())
print(words)
characters = 0
for word in words:
    characters += len(word)
    average_word_lengt = characters/words
```

It is giving me an error:

```
'int' object is not iterable
```

What does it mean and how can I make it work?

Comment: `words = len(sentence.split())` `words` is a `int`. `len` returns a `int` which is length.

Comment: Drop the `len` from `len(sentence.split())`. You only want to use it in the end at `average_word_lengt = characters/len(words)` After you un-indent that from the loop of-course...

Comment: `sum(len(w) for w in sentence.split())/len(sentence.split())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The main issue:

The following statement returns `words` as an integer.  Therefore you cannot iterate.

```
words = len(sentence.split())
```

Given that you want to iterate over your list of words, try this instead:

```
words = sentence.split()
n_words = len(words)
```

#### In more detail:

Here is an updated and working version of your code, using the example above:

```
sentence = input("Give your sentence: ")
# Updated here -->
words = sentence.split()
n_words = len(words)
# <--
print(words)
characters = 0
for word in words:
    characters += len(word)
    average_word_length = characters/n_words  # <-- and here.
```

If you'd like to take this a step further using a syntax called [list comprehension](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-list-comprehensions-in-python-3) (which is very useful!), here is another example:

```
words = input("Give your sentence: ").split()
avg_len = sum([len(w) for w in words])/len(words)

print('Words:', words)
print('Average length:', avg_len)
```

Comment: Interesting use of sed syntax in a comment.  Edited.

Comment: Thanks so much! This error is fixed. But now when i run it i get this 
`1.0
2.0
3.0
4.0
5.0`

Comment: @Katerina You get `1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0` because you left that code inside the loop... ① with a loop, count the no. of characters ② after the loop (and you have to dedent your code to signify Python the loop is finished) you can compute the mean value of word length and print it

Comment: @Katerina - Just updated to show an example of your code with the edit, as well as some extras if you want to take your learning a step further.

Comment: @Katerina - My please, glad to help.  If you’re happy with the answer, may I ask you to please upvote and accept the answer?  Cheers!

Comment: Of course! I've done it now, hope I pressed the right button!

Answer (score 1):

you cannot iterate on length. I guess you need to first get all string len; get the sum and then get average

```
import functools

sentence = input("Give your sentence:")
word_lens = list(map(lambda x: len(x), sentence.split()))
sums = functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, word_lens, 0)
print(round(sums / len(word_lens)))
```

or

```
sentence = input("Give your sentence:")
word_lens = list(map(lambda x: len(x), sentence.split()))
sums = 0
for l in word_lens:
    sums += l
print(round(sums / len(word_lens)))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is there a way to do it somehow without functools but through loops?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply iterate the string directly

```
sentence = input ("Give your sentence:")
word_count = {} #dictionary to store the word count
for word in sentence:
    if word in word_count.items(): #check if word is in the dictionary
        word_count[word] +=1 #adds +1 if already is
    else:
        word_count[word] = 1 #adds the word on the dict
result=len(sentence)/len(word_count) #this will divide the total characters with total single characters
print(result)
```

Comment: Ohh this works perfectly and is sooo helpful, thank you so much for your time!!

Comment: just be careful, if you input a number this will blow up, it only works with strings

Comment: Thanks so much. Ohh but now I found out that I have to do this task without the use of collections or dictionary

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12761510/python-how-can-i-calculate-the-average-word-length-in-a-sentence-using-the-spl this seems what you are looking for

Comment: Thanks! I have tried it and for some reason every time I recieve TypeError: 'int' object is not callable when I use the code from the suggested solutions