# How to create new pandas df column matching string length of another column with random consonant strings?

Tags: python, pandas

I am piloting a language experiment and would like to test several masking options to interrupt the orthographic processing of my stimuli. One option that I would like to test is consonant strings length-matched to my stimuli. For example, I have a stimulus "bakers slice loaves" and I would like to populate that row in a new column with something like "ntjwsk mwsfp jklwsc", for stimulus "cars drive miles" I would populate that row of the new column with something like "tplk wsdpt bvtrl"

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You could start by figuring out a function that does this string matching. If all your examples are just words separated by whitespace, you can try something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12761510/python-how-can-i-calculate-the-average-word-length-in-a-sentence-using-the-spl to get a list of the words. That way you can use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823316/generate-a-random-letter-in-python to create random consonant words for each original one. Let's say your function is randomize(sentence). Then you can do

```
df['new'] = df['original'].apply(randomize)
```.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

## The solution

If you aim for random strings of consonants, the following would work:

```
import random
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"stimulus": ["bakers slice loaves", "cars drive miles", "winter is coming"]})

def transform(c):
    return random.choice("bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz")

df["transformed_stimulus"] = df.apply(lambda row: "".join([y if y in [" "] else transform(y) for y in row["stimulus"]]), axis=1)
```

Otherwise, you can also define your own rules in `transform` function for transforming each letter.

## Background for the solution

The solution utilizes [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) for handling the individual stimulus strings first by running each letter through the transform function. Then the [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method joins the transformed letters again as a complete string. The second list `[" "]` omits whitespaces and you can add other characters too. E.g., `[" ", "a", "e"]` omits whitespace, a, and e characters.